# Missing 'Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine' in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ms-access

I've got several users that need to import / export ACCDB Access files into out of SQL Server.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to get 'Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine' to show up as a data source despite installing / uninstalling seemingly every different bit version of the driver:

We are running SQL Server 64 bit Enterprise 2012 on Server 2008 R2 64 bit. No Office is installed on the server itself.

I'm curious to see what is the proper configuration, because nothing is working for me! Wondering if I'm missing another component.

Used the following drivers to no avail:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&WT.mc_id=soc-n-%5BTR%5D-loc-%5BServices%5D-%5Bfarukc%5D&id=13255

Also have tried this:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Comment: From the first link, which version did you install? IIRC, SSMS is 32bit so you'd need to install that one for this to work. Also, are you doing this on your server or on a workstation?

Comment: I've tried both. This is going on a server.

Answer (score 1):

The driver must be installed on whatever server you are on when you connect. So if you're on your laptop and using Management Studio to connect to SQL Server then the driver needs to be on your laptop.

Comment: As stated above the computer that is exporting the data needs to have the  correct ODBC drivers installed. If you are doing the export from the database server itself (for instance using SSIS) you will have to install the access drivers on the server set the runtime to use either 64 or 32 bit engine (for Office 12 you are better off using the  32bit drivers and run dtexec with the /X86 startup switch). If the client is exporting to access from SSMS or other client application it will need to have the drivers (or office) installed.